# How to define seed file for Rails Apartment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, apartment-gem

I have set up the schema file but unable to define seed file for tenant such that it can run only for tenant migration only. Also I ma trying to create schema once a user has been created and its tenant is created.

```
    require 'apartment/elevators/subdomain'

    #
    # Apartment Configuration
    #
    Apartment.configure do |config|

      config.excluded_models = ["Admin","Contractor", "ContractorPackage","ContractorTransaction","Country","Currency","Faq","FaqCategory","Language","Package","Page","PaymentType","Setting","TempTransaction","Testimonial","Timezone","Tutorial"]

      # use postgres schemas?
      config.use_schemas = true

       config.tenant_names = lambda{ Contractor.pluck("CONCAT('contractor_',id)") }
    end

    # overriding module schema file here
    module Apartment

      class << self
            def database_schema_file
                @database_schema_file=Rails.root.join('db', 'contractor_schema.rb')
            end
        end

    end


    Rails.application.config.middleware.use 'Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain'
```

Comment: Rake db:seed will do it.

Comment: It will seed for public schema also. I want to run for only user/tenant

Comment: There is a lot of code here, most of it comments; can you clear out the comments to simplify what you are presenting and limiting the code to what applies directly to the question (it could be all the code here).

Comment: Were you able to get it working?

Answer (score 17):

In your seeds.rb file, wrap your code in a check for the current tenant. I don't have anywhere to test this right now, but the following code should get you close:

```
unless Apartment::Tenant.current == 'public'
    #Insert seed data
end
```

If you want to seed a tenant manually you should be able to run `Apartment::Tenant.seed`

To get the seeds.rb file to run when a tenant is created add:

```
config.seed_after_create = true
```

to your apartment initializer file.

For your example:

```
Apartment.configure do |config|

  config.excluded_models = ["Admin","Contractor", "ContractorPackage","ContractorTransaction","Country","Currency","Faq","FaqCategory","Language","Package","Page","PaymentType","Setting","TempTransaction","Testimonial","Timezone","Tutorial"]

  # use postgres schemas?
  config.use_schemas = true

  config.tenant_names = lambda{ Contractor.pluck("CONCAT('contractor_',id)") }

  config.seed_after_create = true
end
```

Comment: but how can we run seed command from model? Lets say in user module there is a function after_create: create_schema
def create_schema
#create tenant command
#>> How can I run seed command here ?????
end

Comment: Just added info about how to do that

Comment: Can you add the actual error to the question and the pertinent code that is causing the error?

Comment: @rdubya 's answer works perfectly fine.But I need some thing more like to run the seed on background. Because I need to seed all the countries in world with all their state and few other things. it is taking almost 3 mints to complete the seed and the user doesn't get notification till all the seed completes. so I need to run it background . any suggestion on that.

Comment: The correct way of writing the condition is actually `unless Apartment::Tenant.current == 'public'` (skip _tenant)