# Seeding data with Apartment gem for new schemas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

How can I seed a new tenant in a multi-tenant app that uses the Apartment gem for scoping?

I added the following to seeds.rb but it doesn't seem to work with apartment:

```
tenants = Tenant.create([
{
  name: 'User1',
  domain: 'user1'
},
{
  name: 'User2',
  domain: 'user2'
}
])
```

Even is the database is blank, seeds.rb tries to create the schema twice and fails with this error when I do `rake db:seed`:

```
Apartment::TenantExists: The schema user1 already exists.
```

Comment: hope u didnt forget to do rake db:seed

Comment: Yes, the error happens when I do rake db:seed. I've updated the question.

Comment: Your question may be a duplicate. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27343169/1322092

Answer (score 4):

Rails rake runs tasks for each tenants/schemas your are trying to create. So run your creation or seeding tasks by first checking if the current schema is a public.

Something like this would do.

```
if Apartment::Tenant.current == 'public'
  Apartment::Tenant.create('tenant1')
  Apartment::Tenant.create('tenant2')
end
```